# How do I download a CSV from an API using Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, csv, redux-toolkit

I am being delivered a CSV file from a REST API. How can I tell the app to download it?

It is already a csv so I won't need to create a file out of Json. The content-Type being delivered from the API is 'text/csv' already. When I preview the response in the network window, I see the text data there as expected.

[image]

However, I am not sure how to trigger a csv download from my code. Currently I am using RTKQuery, and when I receive JSON from the API, I can handle it normally like this:

```
    const { data: queryData, loading: loadingQueryData } = useQueryDataHook(
      { time, getCSV: false },
      { skip: !submitForm },
    );

    console.log(queryData) //<- when I receive json from the API, I can log it here like normal. Then I can download it to csv using a blob

      const url2 = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([queryData]))
      const link2 = document.createElement('a')
      link2.href = url2
      link2.setAttribute('download', "myfilename.csv")
      document.body.appendChild(link2)
      link2.click()
      link2.remove()
```

But, when I instead receive the same data as a csv instead of json:

```
    const { data: queryData, loading: loadingQueryData } = useQueryDataHook(
      { time, getCSV: true },
      { skip: !submitForm },
    );

    console.log(queryData) // <--- this will be undefined and I can't do anything with it!
```

How do I need to change this to download that csv data I received to the client?